# Need to exclude certain files from the entire folder using a whitelist text file

Tags: batch-file, whitelist

I'm having a problem with excluding certain files from the entire folder with using a whitelist text file. Currently I'm working on batching scripting

```
for /f "tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (whitelist.txt) do
(
  for %%i in ("list\*") do 
  (
   if not "%%i"=="%%x" 
   (
   echo %%i
   )
 )
)
```

Need some guidance here thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating the directory for each line in whitelist.txt

Whithout knowing what is in whitelist.txt, this is an aproximation to the problem

inside `whitelist.txt`

```
one.txt
two.txt
this is data.txt
```

Then you can do something like

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (
    'dir /b ^| findstr /v /b /e /i /l /g:whitelist.txt'
) do echo %%f
```

Generate the listing of files (and folders, if you want to exclude them, add /a-d to dir command) getting only the filenames (`/b`), and filter with `findstr`. Parameters are : take the search strings from whitelist.txt (`/g:whitelist.txt`), content of whitelist.txt are literal strings (`/l`), ignore case (`/i`), search strings should match from begin (`/b`) to end (`/e`) of line, and only return lines not matching (`/v`).

Comment: @user3145735, thanks are nice, but don't forget to accept the answer if this worked for you. That will give you +2 rep, give the answer author +15, and mark the question as answered. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more info.

Comment: Hi, just to ask, what if my .txt file contain the full path of the file ?? what should I change to make this work ?? 

c:\temp\one.txt